# What does "The skis who dreamed it all up" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I heard in a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/2FHv1CcBJ_k?t=184) this line:

> There's a particular schadenfreude to imagining a bunch of rich kids eating sad cheese sandwiches and sleeping in FEMA tents, and an even bigger schadenfreude to imagining the **skis** eating chili in the mess hall. ([source](https://youtu.be/2FHv1CcBJ_k?t=184))

The *skis* supposedly refers to the con artist Billy McFarland. But what does "skis" mean here? Or did I mishear it? I don't think it is "git" or "kid".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think he's calling the person a [skeeze](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Skeeze)